# How to split a string into 2 equal parts in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I want to divide a string like this:

```
String = "Titanic";
```

into two strings of equal length, and if it isn't divisible by 2 it will have 1 letter or extra on first or second part. like this

```java
//if dividle by 2
Str1 = "BikG";
Str2 = "amer";

//if it isnt dividle by 2
Str1 = "Tita";
Str2 = "nic";
```

Comment: in other words, the question is do my homework, well my friend, this is not the right place to ask for this

Answer (score 2):

You can do it for example like this:

```
String base = "somestring";
int half = base.length() % 2 == 0 ? base.length()/2 : base.length()/2 + 1;
String first = base.substring(0, half);
String second = base.substring(half);
```

Simply when `n` is the string's length, if `n` is divisible by 2, split the string in `n/2`, otherwise split in `n/2 + 1` so that first substring is one character longer than second.

Comment: this works, still a beginner here>>> and I love this community

Answer (score 0):

What do you do to divide an odd number e.g. `15` with the same requirement?

You store the result of `15 / 2` into an `int` variable say

```
int half = 15 / 2
```

which gives you `7`. As per your requirement, you need to add `1` to `half` to make the first half (i.e. `8`) and the remaining half will be `15 - 8 = 7`.

On the other hand, in case of an even number, you simply divide it by `2` to have two halves.

You have to apply the same logic in the case of a `String` as well. Given below is a demo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int half;
        String str1 = "Titanic";
        half = str1.length() / 2;
        String str1Part1 = str1.substring(0, half + 1);
        String str1Part2 = str1.substring(half + 1);
        System.out.println(str1Part1 + ", " + str1Part2);

        String str2 = "HelloWorld";
        half = str2.length() / 2;
        String str2Part1 = str2.substring(0, half);
        String str2Part2 = str2.substring(half);
        System.out.println(str2Part1 + ", " + str2Part2);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
            String str = in.nextLine();
            half = str.length() / 2;
            System.out.println(str.length() % 2 == 1 ? str.substring(0, half + 1) + ", " + str.substring(half + 1)
                    : str.substring(0, half) + ", " + str.substring(half));
            System.out.print("Enter Y to continue or any input to exit: ");
        } while (in.nextLine().toUpperCase().equals("Y"));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Tita, nic
Hello, World
Enter a string: Arvind
Arv, ind
Would you like to continue? [Y/N]: y
Enter a string: Kumar
Kum, ar
Would you like to continue? [Y/N]: Y
Enter a string: Avinash
Avin, ash
Would you like to continue? [Y/N]: n
```

**Note:**

1. `%` is a modulo operator.
2. Check [String substring​(int beginIndex, int endIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) and [String substring​(int beginIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) to learn more about `substring` functions of `String`.
3. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html to learn about the ternary operator.

Answer (score -1):

You could use String.substring() for this purpose:

```java
String s = "Titanic";

int half = (s.length()+1)/2;

String part1 = s.substring(0, half);
String part2 = s.substring(half);

System.out.println(part1); // Prints: Tita
System.out.println(part2); // Prints: nic
```

Here `(s.length()+1)/2` will auto-truncate `0.5` if it occurs because the division is between ints.